# Uniform probability measure on integers and arithmetic progressions

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, puzzle, arithmetic-progressions

Does there exist a probability measure on the integers such that, the probability of any two arithmetic progressions with the same difference part, is the same?

We assume the probability measure is defined over the power set of the integers. Hence, a probability measure corresponds to a sequence of positive (non-negative) numbers $\{p_z\}_{z \in \mathbb{Z}}$ which sum up to one.

Comment: How do you define the probability of an arithmetic progression ? sum of the probabilities of all the number in the progression ?

Answer (score 5):

If I understood well, denoting $p$ this probability measure defined on $\mathcal P(\mathbb Z)$, you want that for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$, $p(a+c\mathbb Z)=p(b+c\mathbb Z)$?

I'm afraid such a probability measure does not exist.

Indeed, let $x\in\mathbb Z$. For all $n\in\mathbb N^*$, you have
$$
p(n\mathbb Z)=p(1+n\mathbb Z)=\cdots=p(n-1+n\mathbb Z),
$$
and
$$
p(n\mathbb Z)+p(1+n\mathbb Z)+\cdots+p(n-1+n\mathbb Z)=p(\mathbb Z)=1,
$$
hence
$$
p(x+n\mathbb Z)=\frac1n\cdot
$$

We deduce that
$$
p(\{x\})\le p(x+n\mathbb Z)\le\frac1n\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0,
$$
and therefore $p(\{x\})=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb Z$, which implies $p(\mathbb Z)=0$.